# Spring Security log in working locally but not on live site

Tags: java, hibernate, authentication, spring-security, authorization

My application is structured with Java and Spring Security. I have two ways to log in, one is using windows log in (aka active directory), the other is using a password created by an admin user. Both of these are working when I run locally through IntelliJ but when I deploy the app to the server, it only lets people using windows login credentials log in. If you try to log in with a custom made login on the live site, it just refreshes the login page and removes the entered username and password. I am not getting any errors. Also, when a user admin creates the custom log in, it is stored in a sql table, with the password hashed. So the create function works/user exists, just logging in is not working. Any idea what might be the cause... Not sure if I should be looking at the code or the server connection.  I use Tomcat and IIS to host this site.

Web Config File

```html
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   @Value("${ad.hg.url}")
    private String AD_HG_URL;

    @Value("${ad.hp.nt.url}")
    private String AD_HP_NT_URL;

    @Autowired
    DBAuthorizationFetcher dbAuthorizationFetcher;

    @Autowired
    ManualUserDetailsService manualUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/specialSplit/**");

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**","/js/**","/images/**","/login","/accessDenied","/loginFailed","/changePassword","/resetPassword").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/newClient","/callLogs/**","/addClient","/saveClient","/delete/**","/save/**","/specialSplit/**").hasRole("OLIDB_ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/admin","/toggle/user/**").hasRole("USER_ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().hasRole("OLIDB_USER").and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler()).successForwardUrl("/")
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied")
                .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        //authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(databaseAuthenticationProvider);
        authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("HEFFGROUP.COM",AD_HP_NT_URL));
        authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("HG",AD_HG_URL));
        authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(manualAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(String domain,String url) {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(domain, url);
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(dbAuthorizationFetcher);
        return provider;
    }

    public DaoAuthenticationProvider manualAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider
                = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(manualUserDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11));
        return authProvider;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @Prakash, I was not able to solve the problem, but I did figure out the issue was with the 2nd line of code in the Configure function. It was getting hung up here: authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("HG",AD_HG_URL));   Luckily I didn't need this line and the line above it, so I removed this line of code and it is now working fine. But not sure if that is helpful for your project!